# REST API : Common Resource Model (Wrapper) for returns

Tags: rest, api-design

To summarize: Is it ok for the returned object of an API call to be different than the object that must be submitted from the caller.

Let me illustrate:

Given two APIs: ***Food*** & ***Sport*** (the resource), both with standard CRUD operations, and whose signatures are standard.

Example:

- GET :  ... /resource/{id}
- POST : ... /resource
- PUT : ... /resource/{id}
- DELETE : ... /resource/{id}

Calling PUT / POST require the payload to contain the object model e.g. ***FoodModel*** or ***SportModel***

The question is:  Is there anything wrong with having all calls (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) return a common datamodel who has a nested object that has the serialized resource where needed.

> Example of **required model to be sent from caller** for POST
>   .../**sport**

```
{
  name: "soccer",
  popularity : "high"
}
```

> Example of **return** model for GET .../**sport**/{1}

( ! GET return, not the response from the POST (thought that too may be a TransactionModel)

```
{ "TransactionModel":{
                      correlationId: "83abaf27-3e87-43e5-a4ae-29eda793aff5",
                      anotherProperty1 : "...",
                      anotherProperty2 : "...",
                      resourceType : "Sport"
                      resourceValue : {
                                  name : "Soccer",
                                  popularity: "high",
                                  createdDate: "2019-06-05 23:06:32.923"
                                 }

}
```

So to clarify, calling these endpoints require their respective models in the payload (for POST & PUT), so **SportModel / FoodModel**

My response object is a **TransactionModel** with the desired resources model contained therein.
This will happen for all resources (Sport, Food, Rule, Person, etc...)

If you have any articles, RFC documents, or anything to argue for or against this approach. Please also provide.

Thank you

Comment: You're not doing REST but RPC here. Mike Amundsen stated it perfectly that *Your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your affordance model*. In addition to that, you have [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) instead of letting client and API negotiate about representation formats understood by both parties. While the URI is not of relevance to clients in REST, I wonder about `PUT .../resources`. PUT basically means replace the representation that is available with what is provided in the payload

Comment: Did you intend PUT : ... /resource/{id} in your examples?

Comment: @RomanVottner, would you please put your response in the form of an answer. 
Also, I have and am digesting the links  you provided. With respect to the specific comment of "typed resources", I understand that the route provided is implying a type. Yes it is true that http://example.com/fgx27-yw could represent any type. But I'm not sure what to do with that statement. Why cannot the route reflect the type? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Thank you very much for the comment and the links. Let's continue this in an "Answer"? :)

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, yes I did. I've updated the post, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is: Is there anything wrong with having all calls (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) return a common datamodel who has a nested object that has the serialized resource where needed.

Short answer: No.

Somewhat longer answer: No, not under ideal circumstances.  But it's not impossible to make a mess that way either.

The world wide web is the reference application for the REST architectural style.  HTML documents are commonly delivered as representations of resources, and likely you will have noticed that there can be a fair amount of... ceremony?... in an HTML document that is not directly related to the resource state.

And lets face it -- regardless of what your representation is, that representation itself is getting embedded within an HTTP message, carrying its own meta data.

The important thing is that the client and server share a common understanding of the semantics of the representation.  Better still if that common understanding were designed so that it can easily be extended in a backwards/forwards compatible way.

Architecturally, resources are not limited to one and exactly one representation.  So you could choose to support both `application/json` and `application/prs.my-custom-app+json`, serving up the richer implementation to those clients that are sufficiently well bred to ask for it.

> Are you suggesting that if the "Accept" header was only specified for "application/json" the response would be the expected model of the resource, e.g. SportModel. Where as "application/pry.my-custom-app+json" would return the "TransactionResult" model?

Yes, in exactly the same way that a client asking for `text/plain` might get a different representation of a resource than a client asking for `text/html`.

Here's a [2008 comment from Roy Fielding](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) that might give you a clearer idea where this is coming from

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think you have some valid points that I'm taking into consideration.  But If you get a chance check out @RomanVottner 's comment (I've asked him to put it in the form of an answer).

I'm going to explore your last statement about the "Accept: application/json" & "Accept: application/prs.my-cust-app+json". 

Are you suggesting that if the "Accept" header was only specified for "application/json" the response would be the expected model of the resource, e.g. *SportModel*. Where as "application/pry.my-custom-app+json"  would return the "TransactionResult" model?

Answer (score 0):

No! you're not doing anything wrong.

But I prefer to have different representation object for each request and response because at the initial stage of the project it looks cool but with time there is different requirements for GET response/request or say POST response/request which will mess your code as you will be trying to handle these things with that common data model or say representation object.

I used to do in the same way you are doing but then I learnt with time. It will increase your work for now but makes your future development much easy.

Comment: If I understand your comment and concern correctly, the model which is used in the request and is contained in the response via the property "ResourceValue" can change as the model evolves.